# Annihilator notation $M^{00}$ in Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have a fairly simple question. Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra on pg. 102 defines the annihilator of a set $M$ in the vector space $V$ as

$$
M^0 = \{f \in V^* \ | \ f(M) = \{0\}\}
$$

which is easily understood, but he then goes on to use the notation $M^{00}$ in the next theorem. Does this just mean $(M^0)^0$? I believe it does, but I wanted to verify this.

Comment: Yes that's correct.